# What methods are there to send value to a wallet via internal transactions?

Tags: ether

I'm familiar with direct transfer via contract and self-destruct method, which can be seen in this screenshot:

[image]

Are there any other methods of replenishing the wallet like these, so that it would be in internal transactions?

Answer (score 0):

The only other method I know to send value is when the recipient is the `fee_recipient` (aka block.coinbase) of the block.

However, etherscan doesn't list them in the internal transactions (last I checked).